# Bundling 32-bit python with py2app application on Mac OS X 10.6

Tags: macos, 32-bit, py2app

I am trying to bundle a python application with a wxPython GUI on Mac OS X 10.6 Server, to be able to distribute it on later Mac OS X versions as well.

The issue than I am running into is that I can't get py2app to bundle the 32-bit python executable with the app, or to force python to run as 32-bit.

I tried running:

```
defaults write com.apple.versioner.python Prefer-32-Bit -bool yes
```

But it only applies to running the app with python directly, not after running py2app. I also tried using a plist with the LSArchitecturePriority option, tried using flags like -prefer-ppc, but nothing seems to work. I also tried downloading a 2.6 version of Python from the web, but I can't figure out how to use it to bundle 32-bit py2app apps (I get an error import compat from altgraph).

I keep getting the no 64-bit architecture found error. How can I get around this?

Answer (score 2):

Use the py2app option --arch=fat
That will strip the 64-bit code from the embedded python interpreter.
You can put the option in the setup.py file too.

https://pythonhosted.org/py2app/options.html

https://pypi.python.org/pypi/py2app/

py2app 0.6.4

```
Added option '--arch=VALUE' which can be used to select the set of architectures for the main executable. This defaults to the set of architectures supported by the python interpreter and can be used to drop support for some architectures (for example when you're using a python binary that supports both 32-bit and 64-bit code and use a GUI library that does not yet work in 64-bit mode).

Valid values for the argument are archectures used in the list below and the following groups of architectures:
    fat: i386, ppc
    fat3: i386, x86_64, ppc
    univeral: i386, x86_64, ppc, ppc64
    intel: i386, x86_64
```